# secure microservice spring boot app with keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, microservices, keycloak, netflix-zuul

I have 4 microservices
eurekaService on port 8761,
productService on port 8083,
companyService on port 8082, and
proxyService on port 8085
and I want to secure my application through keyCloak what is the best practice to implement my security config 
do I have to create a security service (securityService)
or configure each microservice separately
or configure the security config at the proxy level
what's the best practise  to implement keycloak

github repo : https://github.com/dali05/my-first-microservice.git

Comment: I think that keycloak isn't important in this question. When  you talk about pattern, it always depends on several things. Firstly, are all your microservices dependent from each others or some can continue to work even if one is down?

Comment: can you explain to me what is the difference, whether they depend or not
I am a beginner in microservice                                                                             
thanks

Comment: Arf. That's bad. Not your fault. Anyway, Microservices are trendy because they solve some issues that you can have with Monolith. It solves some, and implies tradeoffs. One of them is the resiliency: you service must be robust to service disruption and handle gracefully the errors. If your services are strongly dependent and can't work if one on piece of the puzzle is missing, build a monolith, your microservices are too micro! Reach me on twitter or linkedIn, it will be easier to discuss! (especially if you are french!! Your nickname sounds very frenchy!!!)